# Is there a way to replace a range of characters in a string using gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to replace every character except the last 4 with a "#"...like you would see on a credit card statement. I have accomplished this using the Array#each method to iterate through indexes [0..-4] and then another for [-4..-1] and shoveling results from both into a new string. I'm thinking that maybe this could be better done with regex? But I am new to regex, and google hasn't turned up anything I can use in regards to replacing an entire range without losing the length of the string. I have tried

```
str.gsub(str[0..-5],'#')
```

(and a few other things) but it replaces the entire range with a single character. How can I accomplish my goal using regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, this is possible with regex.

```
> "12345678".gsub(/.(?=.{4})/, "#")
=> "####5678"
> "12345678901234".gsub(/.(?=.{4})/, "#")
=> "##########1234"
```

**Explanation:**

`.(?=.{4})` matches a character only if it's followed by atleast four characters. So it matches all the characters except the last four chars because from the last, fourth character is followed by 3 characters not 4. So it fails to match the 4th char from the last. Likewise for 3rd, 2nd, 1st chars (*from the last*).

**OR**

```
> "12345678901234".gsub(/(?!.{1,4}$)./, "#")
=> "##########1234"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO6zN0/1)

Comment: Sweeeeet!!!! Works like a charm. Now I just need to pick it apart to understand what it is doing, thanks!!! I will mark this as the answer in a few mins SO allows me to;)

Comment: @HolyMoly i explained little bit. I think the explanation i added will help you.

Comment: Avinash, (in general) when an explanation of a regex is requested or called for, consider writing the regex separately using the 'extended' option (`r  = /.../x`) so you can explain each element--on a separate line--with a comment. It would be fast for you and clear to the reader.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again @Avinash Raj...and that demo is great!